# Laravel distinct users by gender and count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am wondering how I can count the number of males/females/na users in my database, using Laravel Eloquent model.

I want this to happen in one query and to receive the following array:

```
[
 ['male' => 3],
 ['female' => 4],
 ['na' => 5],
]
```

Something like that:

```
$users->pluck('gender', 'count(*)')->unique();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$q = User::select('gender', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
       ->groupBy('gender')
       ->get();
```